# Export view details from Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, sql

I don't see a way of exporting this view from a journey activity

[image]

I've tried with SQL but I only see one activity.

```
SELECT sub.EmailAddress as email_address, ja.ActivityExternalKey FROM
    _Sent s
JOIN
    _JourneyActivity ja ON ja.JourneyActivityObjectID = s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
JOIN
    _Journey j ON j.VersionID = ja.VersionID
JOIN 
    ent._subscribers sub ON sub.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE
     j.JourneyName = 'your_journey'
```

How can I programmatically get the contacts that went through a specific activity ?

Comment: when there are no many records you can copy and paste into excel

Answer (score 1):

In your current SQL, you are searching for subscribers in the journey that received an email. However, on the screenshot, you have Update Contact Activity, which is not anyhow related to the email send.

To find people who passed Update Contact Activity and build a similar view on those contacts you would need to utilise [REST API to search through the journeys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getInteractionCollection.html)

You can check Zuzanna's article on that [here](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/27/get-journey-history-by-filtering-the-definition-id-via-api/).

Comment: yeah wanted to avoid that, but I guess there is no other option